# Cardinality of sum-set

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Let $X\subset R$ and $Y \subset R$ where X and Y have finite cardinalities. Let also,
$a,b \in R$. How to show that $|aX+bY|=|X||Y|$ almost everywhere (measure of $(a,b) \subset R^2$ such that $|aX+bY|<|X||Y|$ is 0) ?  Where we define $|aX+bY|=\{ax+by:x \in X, y \in Y \}$.

More, specifically let $X=\{x=d_x*z: z \in \mathcal{Z}, d_x \in \mathcal{R}\}$ (so, it's a lattice. Where each point is $d_x$ away from one another.) 
The above is easy if $X=Y$ then the proof of $|aX+bX|=|X||X|$ almost everywhere is fairly simple.   Now what if $Y$ is lattice with $d_y \neq d_x$. How to show it then?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "almost everywhere" in this context?

Comment: The measure of $(a,b)$ that don't satisfy it is 0.

Comment: The measure of $(a,b)$ is never $0$. That cannot be what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear. Maybe like this measure of $(a,b) \subset R^2$ such that $|aX+bY|<|X||Y|$ is 0

Comment: Hint: there are only finitely many possible coincidences of the type $a x_1 + b y_1 = a x_2 + b y_2$, where $(x_1,y_1) \ne (x_2,y_2)$.  Fix $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ and try to describe the set of all $(a,b)$ where $a x_1 + b y_1 = a x_2 + b y_2$.

Comment: You mean something like this $ax_1+by_1=ax_2+by_2$ implies that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}$ and some how show that this is in $\mathcal{Q}$????

Comment: Is that correct? If so how to do it?

Comment: @user63050 What is the measure of that set of $(a,b)$?

Comment: You asking what is the $\mu( (a,b): ax_1+by_1=ax_2+by_2$ )$, right?

Comment: Then $\mu((a,b):\frac{a}{b}=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2})=??$. This where I am stuck. What to do next?

Comment: @user63050 Draw a picture of this set.

Comment: You mean it's just a line on $mathrb{R}^2$? and therefore it has a measure 0??