# Bounds on cardinality of sum-sets.

Tags: number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $Y \subset \mathbb{R}$ where X and Y have finite cardinalities. Let also,
$a,b \in \mathbb{R}/0$. What can we say about cardinality $|aX+bY|=????$

For example we can have  lower bound and upper bound $\max(|X|,|Y|) \le |aX+bY| \le |X||Y|$.
What about more tight bounds?

I am pretty sure one can show that $|aX+bY|=|X||Y|$ for almost all $a,b$, but I don't know how. Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Also, notation means $aX+bY=\{ax+by: x\in X ,y\in Y \}$.

Comment: By $R$, do you mean $\mathbb R$? What does $aX + bY$ mean? You are multiplying sets with set elements, please explain more what you mean.

Comment: Good question. Sorry, about that. See my corrections.

Comment: In this case, I think your bounds are not correct, as $aX + bY$ can be a smaller set than both $X$ and $Y$, if $a$ and $b$ are both $0$.

Comment: @user63050 The lower bound for $|X+Y|$ is very standard: $|X|+|Y|-1$.  How is this different from your other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647851/cardinality-of-sum-set ?

Comment: It's still the same question. I can't figure it out so I decided to rephrase it. I know you gave me a hint but I couldn't go further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $a,b\in\mathbb R$, the map $f_{a,b}\colon X\times Y\to \mathbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto ax+by$ is injective unless there exist $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $y_1,y_2\in Y$ with $a(x_1-x_2)=b(y_1-y_2)$ and $x_1\ne x_2$ or $y_1\ne y_2$. For each such $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ the set $\{\,(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2\mid a(x_1-x_2)=b(y_1-y_2)\,\}$ describes a line in $\mathbb R^2$. By varying $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ we obtain only finitely many lines, so their union is a set of measure $0$. In this sense, for almost all $(a,b)$ the map $f_{a,b}$ is injective, i.e. $aX+bY$ has precisely $|X|\cdot |Y|$ elements.

Comment: why do we get finitely many lines? Is it because $X$ and $Y$ have finite cardinalities?